# Regarding transit visa for less than 10 hours at King Fahd international airport, SA

Tags: visas, transit, saudi-arabia

I am an Indonesian with a Hungarian Resident Permit Holder.

I am travelling to Indonesia on Sept 3, 2023. Departing from Budapest to King Fahd with Wizz Air, and a stopover in King Fahd International Airport for 5 hours before catching my next flight with Etihad to Indonesia.

****Question****
Do I have to apply for a transit visa or is it free without a visa? My research showed that less than 12 hours transit is exempted from transit visa. I just wanted to make sure.

Thanks :)

Comment: I have similar journey coming in. Can you please share how did you manage this trip? Did you get the transit visa?

Answer (score 1):

If the two legs are *not* booked as one itinerary (one Passenger Number Reference) and/or you will need to clear Immigration (eg to collect checked luggage) you will need a visa.

From [IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com)

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
> Passengers transiting through Dammam (DMM), Jeddah (JED), Medina (MED) or Riyadh (RUH) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 12 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

> Only one transit stop-over in Saudi Arabia is permitted.

Comment: This is assuming that the airline agrees and allows you to board.